# How to detect which user is logged in from cookie (php)?

Tags: php, session

I just did this popular little tutorial (http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) to create a user login system. The last point shows you how to check if the user is logged in. I was just wondering how I can tell WHICH user is logged in so I can pull in their own details? Any help would be amazing!

Many thanks,

Joe

Comment: you don't have to differentiate between users - the session system already does that. you just need something simple like `$_SESSION['is_logged_in']` being true/false.

Answer (score 1):

[This piece of code in the tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL#Create_PHP_Functions) explains:

The cookie just saves the session id so PHP knows which $_SESSION var to load.

When a user is logged in you save this data in the SESSION var:

```
  $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id); // XSS protection as we might print this value
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id; 
  $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $username); // XSS protection as we might print this value
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
  $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $password.$user_browser)
```

You save the user id and username in session.Also a login string made from the users *hashed* password and currently used browser.

You can load all that data up when at the start of a page by just accessing `$_SESSION`.

So get the username from `$_SESSION['user_id']` and use it to get this user data from the DB.

This is how you get the user, but more importantly, you must check if the session actually **belongs** to this user.
In this tutorial meaning you have to try and generate the same login_string from the user you just got out of the DB, and match it with the login_string saved in the session.

This way you can make sure this session isn't stolen.

**For example:**

```
$userid_from_session = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password FROM members WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userid_from_session ); // Bind "$userid_from_session " to parameter.
$stmt->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password); // get variables from result.
$stmt->fetch();
//check if username from cookie exists
if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
    //yep, now lets check the rest
    //user must use same browser
    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
    // compare generated login_string with saved one from session
    if($_SESSION['login_string'] == hash('sha512', $db_password.$user_browser){
        // Awesome,  this is the correct user ($user_id)
    } else {
         // The login string is incorrect, this cookie must be hijacked or something.
    }
} else {
    // User doesn't exists, this session is edited or crap
}
```